# Using contentLayoutGuide for constraints

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I´m trying to use a `NSTextView` with the new Vibrant theme in OSX 10.10 after watching the session from WWDC on advanced features of the new UI. My text view is not placed adjacent to the titlebar so I have made the content view fully sized so I can place the text view beneath title bar.

My problem is that I have a `NSView` between the text view and title bar which should be placed directly beneath the title bar but I can not get auto layout to do this for me. In the video they're giving this sample code using the new `contentLayoutGuide` property in `NSWindow`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topEdgeConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:window.contentLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop];
```

However I can not get this to work, whenever I try to install the constraint Xcode gives me

> Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view? That's illegal.

I get that the window property used in the example is not in the subtree of the view since the view is placed inside the window but how am I supposed to access the `contentLayoutGuide` property?

Currently I´m trying to add the constraint in the `-awakeFromNib` method in a subclassed `NSWindow`. Wrong approach maybe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: this solution is no longer acceptable since OS X El Capitan which has a different views hierarchy in a window frame. Look for the [sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29181559/205668) where he suggests to use a new NSLayoutConstraint methods and properties (constraints activation) that were introduced in Yosemite.**

I've faced the same issue yesterday .

Unfortunately, the documentation is lacking the information about where to put this constraint. The new Xcode 'Capture View Hierarchy' feature to the rescue!

When you constrain some properties of a two views you have to place your resulting constraint on the first common ancestor of these views. This is a basic Auto Layout rule.

In your code you reference `window.contentLayoutGuide`, which declared as id, but effectively is a `NSContentLayoutView`. Run your application and capture the view hierarchy. Here is what you should get on Yosemite:

[image]

You have to add your constraint to the `NSThemeFrame` view, because this is the first ancestor which subtree contains both your `myView` and the `NSContentLayoutView`. This private view is managed by the NSWindow, there is no obvious property to get it from the window instance, but we can easily traverse the view-hierachy instead.

Here is a complete code sample:

```
NSWindow* window = <Get the window>;

NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: myView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: window.contentLayoutGuide attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop];

[((NSView*)window.contentLayoutGuide).superview addConstraint: constraint];
```

Comment: As Sam mentioned below, using the `active` property is the way to go. It's *very* bad to assume that the `contentLayoutGuide` is an instance of `NSView`.

Answer (score 9):

In Yosemite, constraints now have an 'active' property that you can set to make the constraint active without placing it on a common ancestor. I think it was created specifically for cases like this where you don't know the common ancestor.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: myView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: window.contentLayoutGuide attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop];
constraint.active = YES
```

Answer (score 8):

I came across this problem recently and thought i would share the recommended way of handling this today. The technique can be seen in the WWDC 2016 Session 239 "Crafting Modern Cocoa Apps". There have been changes in the API, since they released it, so there is a twist.

Following code puts an NSSearchField, named `searchField`, right below the title/tool-bar area by constraining it to the top of the content view using the windows contentLayoutGuide. The following code is added to an NSViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: NSSearchField!
private var titleBarConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func updateViewConstraints() {
   if titleBarConstraint == nil {
      if let topAnchor = (searchField.window?.contentLayoutGuide as? NSLayoutGuide)?.topAnchor {
         titleBarConstraint = searchField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8)
         titleBarConstraint?.isActive = true
      }
   }

   super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

In Interface Builder the NSSearchField is positioned, using autolayout, to match the look during runtime. Click on the top constraint of the NSSearchField and enable the "Placeholder Remove at build time" checkbox.

The contentLayoutGuide still returns `Any?` but it is an NSLayoutGuide. That was the twist.

Comment: Nice answer, but I've an issue. I use this in a NSTabView. When switching to another tab, and coming back to this tab, the constraint is not applied anymore. The `titleBarConstraint` is then not nil and won't be recreated. I could remove the nil test, but that means creating a constraint each time the view will be shown, seems a bit overkill. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I have documented the entire process I went through of getting a scrollview with a textview to scroll under a window's titlebar here (including Apple's  method of constraining things to the top): https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435872/4615448

The same technique of using insets and tracking the caret/cursor will work for you, as well. You could still make your scrollview top guide go to the top of the contentView, and then use the insets to make it appear inside the content view and go under the titlebar. You could overlay other views on top of it, as well, as long as it extended under them. Then, you could update the insets appropriately and it would go behind whatever you needed it to.

(I know, this question is very old--you've probably since figured it out. I came here while trying to figure the same thing out in El Capitan 10.11, so I'm leaving this here for anyone else).

I'm relatively new to OS X development, so all of you pros are welcome to comment on this post or the next with any improvements or insights noted.